# How to simulate World Cup Draw in R

Tags: r, algorithm, simulation

So qualification for the World Cup next year has finished, and the draw takes place in a couple of weeks.

The 32 teams are put into "pots" based on their world rankings, and then drawn into groups so that each group contains a team from each pot. Simple enough.

```
    library(tidyverse)

    seeds <- read_csv("https://gist.github.com/eldenvo/fb0d27fcb5d322b538d06cdc06b1c559/raw/3eaaab91c29d2dde6c9a28377b325844b834df13/seeds.csv")

    head(seeds)

    # A tibble: 6 x 4
       nation  rank   pot        confed
        <chr> <int> <int>         <chr>
    1  Russia    65     1        Europe
    2  Brazil     2     1 South America
    3    Iran    34     3          Asia
    4   Japan    44     4          Asia
    5  Mexico    16     2 North America
    6 Belgium     5     1        Europe

groups <- letters[c(1:8)]

draw <- seeds %>% filter(pot == 1) %>% sample_n(8) %>% mutate(group = groups)

for (i in 2:4){
  df <- seeds %>% filter(pot == i) %>% sample_n(8) %>% mutate(group = groups)

  draw <- bind_rows(draw, df)
}

print(draw)

# A tibble: 32 x 5
      nation  rank   pot        confed group
       <chr> <int> <int>         <chr> <chr>
 1    Russia    65     1        Europe     a
 2 Argentina     4     1 South America     b
 3    Brazil     2     1 South America     c
 4   Belgium     5     1        Europe     d
 5  Portugal     3     1        Europe     e
 6    Poland     6     1        Europe     f
 7   Germany     1     1        Europe     g
 8    France     7     1        Europe     h
 9   England    12     2        Europe     a
10   Uruguay    17     2 South America     b
# ... with 22 more rows
```

There we have each of the 32 teams randomly assigned a group, A through H, according to their pot.

**But**, there is a further constraint: there cannot be two teams from the same confederation drawn into the same group (apart from Europe, where you cannot have more than two).

That means that in the example above, in a real life draw, when in the second round of picks, Uruguay was drawn to be in group B, but Argentina is already there and there cannot be two South American teams in the same group. Uruguay would then be put into group C instead, and a new team drawn for group B. And so on and so forth.

So how would you go about putting those constraints into a simulation in R?